# SQL new attribute join from another table

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query like that

```
select M.mtitel as Attribute from aRel_adr_Merk R 
inner join vMerkmale M on M.mid=R.mid   
where adrid in(" + listdatenids + ")", utilDB.conn()
```

I have another table called as aAdress. I want to bind adrID from aAdressen. But, they have no common attributes. I just want to show adrID also. How may I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
 select adrID, M.mtitel as Attribute from aAdress,aRel_adr_Merk R 
 inner join vMerkmale M on M.mid=R.mid   
 where adrid in(" + listdatenids + ")", utilDB.conn()
```